# Multiple CMakeLists.txt in a project

Tags: cmake

I have a project with two CMakeLists.txt files: CMakeLists.txt (default) and CMakeLists.2.txt. So my directory tree looks like 

`project
    |---- CMakeLists.txt
    |---- CMakeLists.2.txt
    |---- main.cpp
    |---- otherfile.cpp`

I build like:

    `mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake ..
    make`

This uses the default CMakeLists.txt file. How can I specify to build using the CMakeLists.2.txt cmake file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the file name of "CMakeLists.txt".

However, if you need different build configuration for one project, you should use the `option` in cmake:

```
option(BUILD_STATIC_LIBS "Build the static library" ON)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build the shared library" ON)
option(BUILD_TESTS "Build test programs" OFF)
```

And build like this:

```
cmake -D DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=OFF DBUILD_TESTS=ON ..
```

Comment: you mean have separate Cmakefiles and call each with an IF?

Comment: No, i mean one CMakeLists.txt and separate the different configuration with the cmake `option` cmd.   Use like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481647/cmake-if-else-with-option.  And, of couse, you can also combine the two method: option1, include(CMakeList1.txt); option2, include(CMakeList2.txt) in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I think it should be "cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON...".