# Why does CMake uses cache for options?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have vague understanding of what CMake cache is, but I am not sure *why* it is used for options.

When it comes to options it seems like horrible idea.
This is a quote from answer about why [if does not work with options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481647/cmake-if-else-with-option):

> So to test the logic in your CMakeLists, delete the cache each time
> before re-running CMake.

I am not a functional programming person, but for me it is totally insane to have sticky state for options like this.

I presume there is some reason why CMake choose to have this design.
In other words what is the motivation for putting options in cache?

Comment: It's weird that when CMakeLists.txt changes, cache doesn't reflect the change... I'd like to have a list for "you need to clear the cache to take effect."

Comment: Because usual cmake workflow is to initialize something like `cmake -S . -B debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/.cache` once and `cmake --build debug` with possibly `--target install` one or more times.
Do you want to configure cmake and recompile whole project with this long command more than once? Also you can modify a single option `cmake -S . -B debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=AddressSanitize` and recompile/run with address sanitizer in place, why would you want to specify all options all in a single command, every single time when `cmake --build debug` is enough?

Comment: Note: For modifying the settings of an existing project cmake-gui works reasonably well. As for why it has been chosen to implement this kind of functionality: CMake is a meta build system, i.e. it creates the build system, but doesn't build the project itself; Now if you consider that changing the `CMakeLists.txt` should automatically update the project using the existing settings, you'll need to persist those settings somewhere on the file system and this place happens to be the cmake cache.